# Selenium WebDriver C#: Element.Enabled returns True even though element is disabled

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I need to verify if Save button is disabled.
I used Xpath (//a[contains(@id, 'save')])[1] to locate element.
But element.Enabled is returning True, even though Save button is disabled.

```
<a data-info="Save" class="btn btn-primary disabled btn-xs save save_990928 lineItemControl" id="save_990928" data-request-url="/Materials/Save">
   <span class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-lg lineItemControl"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IWebElement.Enabled Property](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Enabled.htm)

> The Enabled property will generally return true for everything except
>   explicitly disabled input elements.

If the element doesn't have `disabled="disabled"` attribute `element.Enabled` will return `true`.

You can parse the `class` attribute to check if it has `disabled` class

```
element.GetAttribute("class").Contains("disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getAttribute ,fetch the attribute value inside a string and then compare using simple if condition .

`String attributeValue =driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpathExpression")).getAttribute("");
if(attributeValue.contains("disabled")){
    //code you want to execute
}`